# Asp.net MVC 4 Client Side Validation Not Work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, asp.net-ajax

Ajax.beginform validation only running in controller. I want validate model in client side .

Example helpers :

```
<label class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(m) m.Name)</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Name,New With{.class="form-control"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(M) M.Name)
```

Scipts :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Admin/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
```

Model Property

```
<Display(Name:="UserName", ResourceType:=GetType(UserStrings))>
<Required(ErrorMessage:="Username is required")>
Public Property Uname As String
```

Web Config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Form :

```
@Using (Ajax.BeginForm("newUser", "Admin", New AjaxOptions With {.InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                            .HttpMethod = "POST",
                                                            .UpdateTargetId = "allusers"}))
```

Comment: Does your model have any `ValidationAttribute` inherited instances from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` in place?  Does your web.config have both `<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />` and `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />`?

Comment: I added web config and model property to question . I think there is no problem here

Comment: What does your form tag look like?

Comment: @cptc Yup, looks correct, and like it should be working. What browsers have you tried, and did you view the debugger within the browser to check for javascript errors?

Comment: @MikeGuthrie Yes I looked chrome console but there is no error here.

Comment: @CorrugatedAir I have added form tag to question you can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. I used this form in partial view. when i copy form to main view client side validation was work fine.

i added this script to partial view and validation works with partial view.

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#newuser"));
```